# Android studio - Where is project directories?

Tags: android, android-studio

I decided to learn some Android development stuff. I downloaded Android Studio, even Android SDK which is not necessary. After createing new project, with default settings, I can't see any subfolders.[image]

I use Ubuntu 13.04. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All right, folks, it seems to be bug with 0.2 version of Android Studio. I had no luck downloading buggy version. In 0.2.10 version bug doesn't appears. Thanks for all!

Answer (score 0):

right mouse click on your project -> properties -> look at the resource path info

Comment: Where do I have to click? I use PhpStorm with the same interface so I know where are project main elements. However, I AM in root directory, but I don't see directories inside of it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the project is not properly opened/imported.

Same problem [here](https://plus.google.com/105368031589847609047/posts/QVMdYQB4P35).

Try to close your project (File -> Close Project). Then in the main Window import your project. Instead selecting your root project folder (I think this wouldn't have an effect) select your "settings.gradle" file of your project. 
A window should appear where you can select the gradle wrapper -> choose "Use default gradle wrapper (recommended)".